# Spark String to date with weird formats

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hello I have a column of Strings named `Last Updated` with this format `February 17, 2017`, when I try to cast it doing:

`.withColumn("Last Updated", date_format($"Last Updated","Month D , Yr"))`

The column ends up all null, what am I doing wrong?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date format is wrong. please refere to [Java SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

it should be `MMMM dd, yyyy`.

==> `.withColumn("Last Updated", to_date($"Last Updated","MMMM dd, yyyy"))`

Comment: I have changed it to ```.withColumn("Last Updated", date_format($"Last Updated","MMMMM d, yyyy"))``` but it still gives the same result...

Comment: hmm i saw on the website you linked me it had 5 'M' instead of 4, it's doesnt work regardless

Comment: To solve this problem I had to use ```to_date``` instead of ```date_format``` incase anyone stumbles upon this post.